# Maven Build Fail in Eclipse (Tests and Plugin)

Tags: maven, spring-boot, maven-eclipse-plugin

I am using Maven Buildin Eclipse IDE for a Spring project for uploading files.[SPRING](https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/). The error is arising from

1-Plugin. I deleted the maven-compiler plugin from /.m2 directory (Windows), but the error still exist. The usual consensus is to delete whole ./m2 directory which is not feasible as I have other projects.

2- The FileUploadTest.java seems to be giving out a lot of errors. Is this due to corrupted jars or error in my pom.xml file?

```
    [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 34.910 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-06-14T11:03:01+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 32M/297M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) on project SpringMVCImage: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /C:/Users/workspace/SpringMVCImage/src/main/java/com/ayman/image/FileUploadTests.java:[6,20] package org.hamcrest does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/workspace/SpringMVCImage/src/main/java/com/ayman/image/FileUploadTests.java:[7,17] package org.junit does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/workspace/SpringMVCImage/src/main/java/com/ayman/image/FileUploadTests.java:[8,24] package org.junit.runner does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/workspace/SpringMVCImage/src/main/java/com/ayman/image/FileUploadTests.java:[11,63] package org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/workspace/SpringMVCImage/src/main/java/com/ayman/image/FileUploadTests.java:[12,45] package org.springframework.boot.test.context does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/workspace/SpringMVCImage/src/main/java/com/ayman/image/FileUploadTests.java:[13,50] package org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/workspace/SpringMVCImage/src/main/java/com/ayman/image/FileUploadTests.java:[14,36] package org.springframework.mock.web does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/workspace/SpringMVCImage/src/main/java/com/ayman/image/FileUploadTests.java:[15,47] package org.springframework.test.context.junit4 does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/workspace/SpringMVCImage/src/main/java/com/ayman/image/FileUploadTests.java:[16,44] package org.springframework.test.web.servlet does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/workspace/SpringMVCImage/src/main/java/com/ayman/image/FileUploadTests.java:[18,26] package org.mockito does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/workspace/SpringMVCImage/src/main/java/com/ayman/image/FileUploadTests.java:[18,1] static import only from classes and interfaces
[ERROR] /C:/Users/workspace/SpringMVCImage/src/main/java/com/ayman/image/FileUploadTests.java:[19,26] package org.mockito does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/workspace/SpringMVCImage/src/main/java/com/ayman/image/FileUploadTests.java:[19,1] static import only from classes and interfaces
[ERROR] /C:/Users/workspace/SpringMVCImage/src/main/java/com/ayman/image/FileUploadTests.java:[20,59] package org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/workspace/SpringMVCImage/src/main/java/com/ayman/image/FileUploadTests.java:[20,1] static import only from classes and interfaces
[ERROR] /C:/Users/workspace/SpringMVCImage/src/main/java/com/ayman/image/FileUploadTests.java:[21,59] package org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/workspace/SpringMVCImage/src/main/java/com/ayman/image/FileUploadTests.java:[21,1] static import only from classes and interfaces
[ERROR] /C:/Users/workspace/SpringMVCImage/src/main/java/com/ayman/image/FileUploadTests.java:[22,58] package org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/workspace/SpringMVCImage/src/main/java/com/ayman/image/FileUploadTests.java:[22,1] static import only from classes and interfaces
[ERROR] /C:/Users/workspace/SpringMVCImage/src/main/java/com/ayman/image/FileUploadTests.java:[23,58] package org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/workspace/SpringMVCImage/src/main/java/com/ayman/image/FileUploadTests.java:[23,1] static import only from classes and interfaces
[ERROR] /C:/Users/workspace/SpringMVCImage/src/main/java/com/ayman/image/FileUploadTests.java:[24,58] package org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/workspace/SpringMVCImage/src/main/java/com/ayman/image/FileUploadTests.java:[24,1] static import only from classes and interfaces
[ERROR] /C:/Users/workspace/SpringMVCImage/src/main/java/com/ayman/image/FileUploadTests.java:[29,2] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol: class RunWith
[ERROR] /C:/Users/workspace/SpringMVCImage/src/main/java/com/ayman/image/FileUploadTests.java:[30,2] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol: class AutoConfigureMockMvc
[ERROR] /C:/Users/workspace/SpringMVCImage/src/main/java/com/ayman/image/FileUploadTests.java:[31,2] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol: class SpringBootTest
[ERROR] /C:/Users/workspace/SpringMVCImage/src/main/java/com/ayman/image/FileUploadTests.java:[35,13] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class MockMvc
[ERROR] location: class com.ayman.image.FileUploadTests
[ERROR] /C:/Users/workspace/SpringMVCImage/src/main/java/com/ayman/image/FileUploadTests.java:[37,6] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class MockBean
[ERROR] location: class com.ayman.image.FileUploadTests
[ERROR] /C:/Users/workspace/SpringMVCImage/src/main/java/com/ayman/image/FileUploadTests.java:[40,6] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Test
[ERROR] location: class com.ayman.image.FileUploadTests
[ERROR] /C:/Users/workspace/SpringMVCImage/src/main/java/com/ayman/image/FileUploadTests.java:[51,6] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Test
[ERROR] location: class com.ayman.image.FileUploadTests
[ERROR] /C:/Users/workspace/SpringMVCImage/src/main/java/com/ayman/image/FileUploadTests.java:[63,6] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Test
[ERROR] location: class com.ayman.image.FileUploadTests
[ERROR] /C:/Users/workspace/SpringMVCImage/src/main/java/com/ayman/image/FileUploadTests.java:[42,9] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method given(java.util.stream.Stream<java.nio.file.Path>)
[ERROR] location: class com.ayman.image.FileUploadTests
[ERROR] /C:/Users/workspace/SpringMVCImage/src/main/java/com/ayman/image/FileUploadTests.java:[47,25] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   variable Matchers
[ERROR] location: class com.ayman.image.FileUploadTests
[ERROR] /C:/Users/workspace/SpringMVCImage/src/main/java/com/ayman/image/FileUploadTests.java:[46,28] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method model()
[ERROR] location: class com.ayman.image.FileUploadTests
[ERROR] /C:/Users/workspace/SpringMVCImage/src/main/java/com/ayman/image/FileUploadTests.java:[45,46] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method status()
[ERROR] location: class com.ayman.image.FileUploadTests
[ERROR] /C:/Users/workspace/SpringMVCImage/src/main/java/com/ayman/image/FileUploadTests.java:[45,26] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method get(java.lang.String)
[ERROR] location: class com.ayman.image.FileUploadTests
[ERROR] /C:/Users/workspace/SpringMVCImage/src/main/java/com/ayman/image/FileUploadTests.java:[53,9] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class MockMultipartFile
[ERROR] location: class com.ayman.image.FileUploadTests
[ERROR] /C:/Users/workspace/SpringMVCImage/src/main/java/com/ayman/image/FileUploadTests.java:[53,47] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class MockMultipartFile
[ERROR] location: class com.ayman.image.FileUploadTests
[ERROR] /C:/Users/workspace/SpringMVCImage/src/main/java/com/ayman/image/FileUploadTests.java:[57,28] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method header()
[ERROR] location: class com.ayman.image.FileUploadTests
[ERROR] /C:/Users/workspace/SpringMVCImage/src/main/java/com/ayman/image/FileUploadTests.java:[56,28] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method status()
[ERROR] location: class com.ayman.image.FileUploadTests
[ERROR] /C:/Users/workspace/SpringMVCImage/src/main/java/com/ayman/image/FileUploadTests.java:[55,26] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method fileUpload(java.lang.String)
[ERROR] location: class com.ayman.image.FileUploadTests
[ERROR] /C:/Users/workspace/SpringMVCImage/src/main/java/com/ayman/image/FileUploadTests.java:[59,9] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method then(com.ayman.image.storage.StorageService)
[ERROR] location: class com.ayman.image.FileUploadTests
[ERROR] /C:/Users/workspace/SpringMVCImage/src/main/java/com/ayman/image/FileUploadTests.java:[65,9] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method given(org.springframework.core.io.Resource)
[ERROR] location: class com.ayman.image.FileUploadTests
[ERROR] /C:/Users/workspace/SpringMVCImage/src/main/java/com/ayman/image/FileUploadTests.java:[68,60] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method status()
[ERROR] location: class com.ayman.image.FileUploadTests
[ERROR] /C:/Users/workspace/SpringMVCImage/src/main/java/com/ayman/image/FileUploadTests.java:[68,26] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method get(java.lang.String)
[ERROR] location: class com.ayman.image.FileUploadTests
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

Here is my pom.xml file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.ayman</groupId>
<artifactId>SpringMVCImage</artifactId>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

 <properties>
    <start-class>com.ayman.image.Main</start-class>
  </properties>
    <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
<!--  Spring Mobile -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.mobile</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-mobile-device</artifactId>
       <version>1.1.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 1):

In Maven, test classes have not to be located in the `src/main/java` directory but in the `src/test/java` directory.
`src/test/java` is indeed the test source directory and only classes located here can use dependencies specified with the `test` scope.

So all your test classes using classes of this dependency cannot compile :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Move your test classes in `src/test/java` and it should solve a large part of your issue.

[This introduction on the directory layout of Maven](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) could probably help you.

Comment: I moved but import com.mastercard.ayman.image.storage.StorageFileNotFoundException;
import com.mastercard.ayman.image.storage.StorageService; canot be resolved. Should I move the *.storage to test folder as well?

Comment: Applicative classes have to be in `src/main/java`.  And classes in `src/main/java`  are usable by classes in `src/test/java`. So it means that these classes are probably not there or not in the correct package. Check that.

Comment: Now on Spring App I am getting this error Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.mastercard.ayman.image.FileUploadController required a bean of type 'com.mastercard.ayman.image.storage.StorageService' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.ayman.image.storage.StorageService' in your configuration. I have Component Scan for the Bean. in SpringBootApplication Why is the error?

Comment: It is a runtime error, so a distinct problem. Please open a new question and specify all relevant information. Someone will very probably address it.